# Image is not responsive with class added

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

as the title says. Here is the code I'm using this theme http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/grayscale/

Edit where is the whole code to make it clear:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
              <!--  <i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>  <span class="light">Start</span> Bootstrap -->
                 <img class="img-responsive" src="img/ssmk_logo.png">
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#weather">Weather Forecast</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#download">Estate Agent</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Stocks</a>
                </li>
                 <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Comment: It's rather unclear as to what, exactly, is wrong. Can you please explain what you're trying to achieve, as in how it should look/act?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/uLhxsc9z  here is JS I'm trying to make the icon be a child to this div and not be larger than navigation bar

Comment: `.img-responsive` makes an image as wide as max(widthOfParentElement, normalWidthOfImage). The issue is that `.navbar-brand` doesn't have a defined width; it'll expand to accommodate its children.

Comment: what is the easiest way to fix all of this? define the width of .nav-brand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should the objective be to get your logo into the Bootstrap navbar, you'll have to resize the image in some way. Your options for that are to do it with CSS, or to make a smaller version of it to be served up to your site. My solution resizes it using CSS.

```css
img {
  margin-top: -11px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 45px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img alt="Brand" src="http://i.imgur.com/9PRm767.png" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Per the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-brand-image) for Bootstrap nav branding using images, this is how you add an image to your navbar instead of text for branding purposes. The documentation also says you'll need to either override some CSS depending on your image. My CSS here gets rid of some of the margin the `navbar-header` creates so the image is nice and flush with the rest of the navbar. Should you want a larger image to be used, you'll need to mess with the width of your navbar.

Using the `img-responsive` class from Bootstrap is not appropriate here due to the widths of various components in the navbar for Bootstrap, which only collapses down in smaller viewports and does not, itself, dynamically resize along all dimensions as the viewport gets wider. The Bootstrap navbar is easily the most inflexible item in the entire framework, but that's not a bad thing because really, you shouldn't be messing with the size of the navbar too much.

Comment: is there anyway to also add text next to the icon so it will be to the right and not below the icon ? like <span>icon</span> ?

Comment: @Hig Place the text in paragraph tags, then add the `navbar-text` class. http://jsfiddle.net/yg6f7af2/ You may want to consider reading up on the documentation for the Bootstrap navbar, as nearly everything you need to know is in there. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: I meant it to still be under </a> clickable link. Sorry for all those questions I'm new to boostrap and I need to finish a simple website for the next week.

Comment: There is, but honestly that's something you should play around with on your own. That's how you'll learn and get better. :)

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**

With the correct closing tags that should work. As you can see if you resize Maradona image, it appears to be responsive. I suggest you to validate your entire HTML and check if there is some error on it.

http://jsfiddle.net/xd1p8pov/

Your html (as we see it) is missing one div and one nav closing tags. Have you tried to inspect the .img-responsive class? By default in Bootstrap should be :

```
.img-responsive {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: can you please upload it in jsfiddle so I can have a look?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uLhxsc9z/ There you go the picture doesn't scale to the navigation bar